# Intermittent server errors sometime on wordpress site

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, hosting

Hi while i am assessing admin panel of wordpress CMS it gives us an error :

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@planetofcoders.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

After I refresh the page it will be resolved. I want to know that why this error occurs and how to resolve this error.....

Comment: Is there anything you might have done that may have caused the error?

Comment: Check your error logs. "More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

Comment: Ask hosting support for server logs

Answer (score 2):

As Cori says, you'll need to consult your logs to know specifically. That being said, the issue being intermittent does narrow things down a bit. In order of likelihood, I bet your problem is:

- **Traffic.** How popular is your blog? Are you experiencing growth? Pageviews equals server load, and server load causes 500 errors in a lot of cases, especially at peak times. If you know your traffic is ramping up, talk to your webhost - and if necessary, get a more robust plan.
- **Plugins.** Relating to the above, if you have added a plugin recently it could be at fault, either because it performs an occasional task that screws the server up or because it increases server load per view and makes your site more sensitive to traffic. Try disabling any recently-added plugins and waiting for the issue to recur.
- **Shared server load.** If you're on a shared hosting plan - as many blogs are - load on a different site on the same machine as you can contribute to your downtime.

The upshot: talk to your host, then if necessary read a FAQ on WordPress optimization.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you'll need to check your logs to see what's going on.

From the error message, it would seem that your website's host has configured your site to use a custom [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) that Apache is having trouble with, and the apache error logs should help to find out what's going on.

There are a number of different intermittent errors that could be causing you problems.  Database connections are one typical one.